# SimpleXml PHP addchild before any child

Tags: php, simplexml, addchild

I know how to add child nodes with SimpleXml and PHP but i have a problem with the orders of those child elements. 
Lets say i have this  xml structure

album
    gallery1
    gallery2
    gallery2
   .
   .
   .
    galleryN
/album

This is how it is right now when I add childs with the basic code

```
$galleryElement = $sxe->addChild("gallery");
```

I want the order of child elements in this case to be on the opposite  the last gallery that i will add to be first child of Album.

example:

album 
    gallery3
    gallery2
    gallery1

/album

Any one knows some trick here

Comment: are you looking for reorder function or a "remove all and reAdd them in the correct order" is enought?

Comment: i dont want to remove and reAdd, i just need some function that when i will  add new gallery this gallery will be the first child (on top of other galleryis)

Comment: Looks like you want to prepend rather than append?  If so, check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092012/simplexml-how-to-prepend-a-child-in-a-node

Comment: @Paul Kehre - Thats what i am looking for, but i can not configue because i use another class for adding CData child. Can you help me to configure out  how to use  public function prependChild($name, $value)
inside my class ?

Comment: @Paul Kehre - OK i configure it, is there a chance your answer to be chosen as winner ?

Comment: I'll add an answer if you want to choose it.  Glad you got it working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to prepend to your container.  Unfortunately simplexml doesn't have this function natively, but this previous answer will assist you in getting it working

[SimpleXML how to prepend a child in a node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092012/simplexml-how-to-prepend-a-child-in-a-node)