# PHP addChild to top of list?

Tags: php, html, css, xml

I'm working with this script below to add text from an input field to an XML file. I'm confused on adding a an item to the top of list, maybe firstChild? Because when ever the PHP posts the text from the input field it adds it to the bottom of the XML tree, is there anyway to have it be the first item on the tree?

```
<?php

if ($_POST['post']) {
$xml = simplexml_load_file('feed.xml');
$item = $xml->channel->addChild('item');
$item->addChild('title', htmlspecialchars($_POST['post']));


file_put_contents('feed.xml', $xml->asXML());
}
?>
```

Here's what I want the XML to look like.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss version="2.0">
    <channel>
        <item>
            <title>Item 3</title>
        </item>
        <item>
            <title>Item 2</title>
        </item>
        <item>
            <title>Item 1</title>
        </item>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

Comment: Don't believe you can specify an insert location with simplexml. But with the full DOM, you can use `insertBefore()` to insert a node at the top of the children list.

Comment: Would insertBefore() replace addChild then?

Comment: No. DOM has appendChild for adding after (or at the end). They both insert nodes, but insert the new node in different locations.

Answer (score 0):

Here the the link for a similar question with the answer

[How to prepend a child in Simple XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092012/simplexml-how-to-prepend-a-child-in-a-node)

```
class my_node extends SimpleXMLElement
{
    public function prependChild($name)
    {
        $dom = dom_import_simplexml($this);

        $new = $dom->insertBefore(
            $dom->ownerDocument->createElement($name),
            $dom->firstChild
        );

        return simplexml_import_dom($new, get_class($this));
    }
}

if ($_POST['post']) {
$xml = simplexml_load_file('feed.xml');
$item = $xml->channel->prependChild('item');
$item->addChild('title', htmlspecialchars($_POST['post']));
file_put_contents('feed.xml', $xml->asXML());
 }
```

Comment: Okay, I see what you guys mean now. But it's not working in my situation for some reason. Still adds the child below the previous one...