# PHP SimpleXMLElement addChild in a loop only show once with largest value

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have an XML file:

```
<include>
    <data>
        <name>Chicken</name>
        <price>1</price>
    </data>
    <data>
        <name>Fish</name>
        <price>5</price>
    </data>
    ...Cut off about 100 lines...
    <data>
        <name>Pig</name>
        <price>105</price>
    </data>
<include>
```

Now, I want to add the ascending `<id>`, right above the `<name>` like this:

```
<include>
    <data>
        <id>1203001</id>
        <name>Chicken</name>
        <price>1</price>
    </data>
    <data>
        <id>1203002</id>
        <name>Fish</name>
        <price>5</price>
    </data>
    ...Cut off about 100 lines...
    <data>
        <id>1203105</id>
        <name>Pig</name>
        <price>105</price>
    </data>
<include>
```

I used the `for` loop, here is my code:

```
$data = <<<XML
<include>
    <data>
        <name>Chicken</name>
        <price>1</price>
    </data>
    <data>
        <name>Fish</name>
        <price>5</price>
    </data>
    ...Cut off about 100 lines...
    <data>
        <name>Pig</name>
        <price>105</price>
    </data>
<include>
XML;
for($i = 1203001; $i <= 1203105; $i++) {
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($data);
    $xml->data->addChild("id", $i);
}
echo $xml->asXML();
```

However, the result I get is that `<id>` only appears once, with the largest value, next to `</data>` instead of the position I want::

```
<include>
    <data>
        <name>Chicken</name>
        <price>1</price>
    <id>1203105</id></data>
    <data>
        <name>Fish</name>
        <price>5</price>
    </data>
    ...
```

Please show me a method to solve this problem. I would appreciate your solution.

Comment: Something I like about SimpleXML is that instead of `addChild()`, you can also use object notation to set new values `$data->id = $i;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're recreating `$xml` from `$data` every time through the loop, so you're discarding the changes you made on the previous iteration.

Initialize `$xml` before the loop. Then loop over the `data` child nodes.

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($data);
$i = 1203001;
foreach ($xml->data as $node) {
    $node->addChild("id", $i++);
}
```

If you want to insert `<id>` at the beginning of the `<data>` node instead of the end, see [SimpleXML how to prepend a child in a node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092012/simplexml-how-to-prepend-a-child-in-a-node)

Comment: I have followed your instructions, although `<id>` has increased by itself but I have problems `<id>`, `<data>` and `</data>` are on the same line, `<id>` is at the end instead of above `<name>` like this: `<id>1203XXX</id></data> <data>`.

Here is a snapshot of the result: [Resuilt](https://i.imgur.com/k2kuqk9.png)

Here is the code: [Code](https://i.imgur.com/dm1So9l.png)

Comment: `SimpleXMLElement` doesn't have a way to add at any place except the end of a node. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092012/simplexml-how-to-prepend-a-child-in-a-node for how you can prepend.

Comment: I did it, using that guide in conjunction with replace. Now I want to move the entire `<id>` up to `<name>`, is there any way?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that, isn't that what that question shows how to do? In general, order of tags in an XML node shouldn't matter.

Comment: Currently, `<id>` is under `<price>`, I would like to ask is there a way to move the entire `<id>` up above `<name>`? Because it is located at the end, the observation is quite difficult.

Comment: Isn't that what the other question explains how to do?

Comment: I need to create a new question?

Comment: If the technique in that question isn't working, you could post a comment there.